# Trying to extract three names from one line using getline

Tags: c++, string

Hi there I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to extract three names (first, middle, last) from one line.

```
cout<< "Please enter your full name" << endl;
  getline(cin, first_name, ' ');
  getline(cin, midLast_name);
```

I take the middle and last name as variable and then split them up. I need to be able to accept a space as a middle name so this is what I'm doing. However, in my conditional statement, the code isn't finding a space even though there is one. Any ideas?

```
if (midLast_name.find(" ") == true)
{
    first_space = midLast_name.find(" ");
    middle_name = midLast_name.substr(0,first_space);
    last_space = midLast_name.rfind(" ");
    last_name = midLast_name.substr(midLast_name.rfind(" ") + 1, full_name.length());

 }
```

Comment: How would you accept a middle name as a space? What if the user types `First<spc><spc><spc><spc><spc>Last`?

Comment: Since `getline()` gets the line, why not just get the line and handle the splitting of that single line?

Comment: Why not get one name per line? It is quite possible to have first, middle or last names with spaces in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string::find(...)` returns the position or `string::npos` if not found, thus your code should compare against `npos` rather than `==true`.

```
size_t firstspace = midLast_name.find(" ");
if (firstspace != string::npos) {
   middle_name= midLast_name.substr(0, firstspace);
   ... 
}
```